# Help with a Gradient problem for implicit equation

Tags: vector-analysis, differential

Consider the functions $(,)=^3$, where $(,)$ is defined implicitly by the equation $^2+^2=5$. Compute the gradient of $w(x,y)$ when $=2$ and $\frac{∂}{∂}=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please edit your question with any attempts or thoughts you have at answering your question. This helps people understand exactly what you need help with and shows that you are putting in an effort.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = x^3+3x^2y\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} $$

As $x = x(y,z)$, we have $$x^2 + 2xy\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + z^2\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0$$

So, as $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = 0$, we get

\begin{align}
x^3 &= \frac{3x^4y}{z^2+2xy} \\
\implies z^2 &= xy \\
\end{align}

So, we have $x^2y+x^2y=5$, which with $x=2$ gives $y=\frac{5}{8}$, $z = \frac{\sqrt 5}{2}$.

We can calculate $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ similarly.